# How to find implicitly deleted default constructors in clang's AST?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libtooling

Consider the following struct definition in `foo.cc`:

```
struct Foo
{
  int &bar;
};
```

Because `bar` has reference type, the implicit trivial default constructor `Foo::Foo()` is implicitly deleted. However, this fact does not seem to be reflected in the AST generated by clang. E.g. running `clang -Xclang -ast-dump foo.cc` results in:

```
`-CXXRecordDecl 0x5612ba4c03b8 <test.cc:1:1, col:24> col:8 struct Foo definition
  |-DefinitionData pass_in_registers aggregate trivially_copyable trivial literal
  | |-DefaultConstructor exists trivial needs_implicit
  | |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
  | |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial needs_implicit
  | |-CopyAssignment trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
  | |-MoveAssignment exists trivial needs_implicit
  | `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial needs_implicit
  |-CXXRecordDecl 0x5612ba4c04e0 <col:1, col:8> col:8 implicit struct Foo
  `-FieldDecl 0x5612ba4c05b8 <col:14, col:19> col:19 bar 'int &'
```

So here it looks like an implicit trivial default constructor exists, but there is no mention of it being deleted. Similarly, the `clang::CXXRecordDecl` API seems to offer no way of determining this either. But shouldn't this information be available at this point (after semantic analysis)? How can I use the clang AST API to find out whether some class's implicit trivial default constructor is implicitly deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Information about deleted implicit constructors is available after using
the `ForceDeclarationOfImplicitMembers` of the
[`Sema`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Sema.html)
(semantic analysis) class.  That will populate the
[`CXXRecordDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html)
with
[`CXXConstructorDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXConstructorDecl.html)
nodes, which can then be iterated over with `CXXRecordDecl::decls`
or visited using a
[`RecursiveASTVisitor`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html).

One tricky bit is getting ahold of the `Sema` object in order to
invoke the required method.  If you are using
the `LoadFromCommandLine` method of
[`ASTUnit`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTUnit.html),
that returns an `ASTUnit` object, which has a `getSema` method.

If you are using
[`ClangTool`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1ClangTool.html),
you can either use `buildASTs` to get `ASTUnit`s directly,
or use `run` with a
[`FrontendAction`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FrontendAction.html)
and use its `getCurrentASTUnit` method.
(The [tutorial](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html)
makes this somewhat difficult because it uses
`newFrontendActionFactory`.  Dealing with that complication could be the
subject of a new question.)

In either case, once the AST nodes for the implicit methods have been
created, the `isDeleted` method
(declared on [`FunctionDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html))
will return `true` if the method has been implicitly or explicitly
deleted.

Finally, be aware that if you use a `RecursiveASTVisitor` to visit the
methods, by default it skips implicitly-defined methods.  To change
that, implement the `shouldVisitImplicitCode` method and have it return
`true`.

### Complete example

Below are sources and tests to make and run a program that report all
constructors, including those that are implicit, and whether they are
deleted.

`deleted-ctor.cc`:

```
// deleted-ctor.cc
// Report deleted constructors.

#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"                 // clang::RecursiveASTVisitor
#include "clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h"                        // clang::DiagnosticsEngine
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticOptions.h"                 // clang::DiagnosticOptions
#include "clang/Frontend/ASTUnit.h"                        // clang::ASTUnit
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"               // clang::CompilerInstance
#include "clang/Sema/Sema.h"                               // clang::Sema
#include "clang/Serialization/PCHContainerOperations.h"    // clang::PCHContainerOperations

#include <iostream>                                        // std::cout
#include <string>                                          // std::string

using std::cout;
using std::string;


class Visitor : public clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<Visitor> {
public:      // data
  clang::ASTUnit *m_astUnit;
  clang::ASTContext &m_astContext;

public:      // methods
  Visitor(clang::ASTUnit *astUnit)
    : m_astUnit(astUnit),
      m_astContext(astUnit->getASTContext())
  {}

  // Convenience methods to stringify some things.
  string locStr(clang::SourceLocation loc);
  string declLocStr(clang::Decl const *decl);
  string typeStr(clang::QualType qualType);

  // By default, AST visitors skip implicit nodes even if they are
  // present in the AST.  Returning true here ensures we will not skip
  // them.
  bool shouldVisitImplicitCode() { return true; }

  // Visitor methods.
  bool VisitCXXRecordDecl(clang::CXXRecordDecl *recordDecl);
  bool VisitCXXConstructorDecl(clang::CXXConstructorDecl *methodDecl);

  // Kick off the traversal.
  void traverseTU();
};

string Visitor::locStr(clang::SourceLocation loc)
{
  return loc.printToString(m_astContext.getSourceManager());
}

string Visitor::declLocStr(clang::Decl const *decl)
{
  return locStr(decl->getLocation());
}

string Visitor::typeStr(clang::QualType qualType)
{
  return qualType.getAsString();
}

bool Visitor::VisitCXXRecordDecl(clang::CXXRecordDecl *recordDecl)
{
  if (recordDecl->getDefinition() != recordDecl) {
    // This is not the definition, so ignore it.
  }
  else {
    cout << recordDecl->Decl::getDeclKindName()
         << " \"" << recordDecl->getQualifiedNameAsString()
         << "\" at " << declLocStr(recordDecl)
         << ":\n";

    // Without this, the implicit members are not in the AST.
    m_astUnit->getSema().ForceDeclarationOfImplicitMembers(recordDecl);
  }

  return true;
}

bool Visitor::VisitCXXConstructorDecl(clang::CXXConstructorDecl *ctor)
{
  cout << "  " << ctor->Decl::getDeclKindName()
       << " \"" << ctor->getQualifiedNameAsString()
       << "\" type=\"" << typeStr(ctor->getType())
       << "\" at "
       << declLocStr(ctor)
       << ": deleted=" << ctor->isDeleted()
       << "\n";

  return true;
}


void Visitor::traverseTU()
{
  this->TraverseDecl(m_astContext.getTranslationUnitDecl());
}


int main(int argc, char const **argv)
{
  // Point 'LoadFromCommandLine' at the clang binary so it will be able
  // to find its compiler headers such as stddef.h.
  argv[0] = CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR "/bin/clang";

  // Boilerplate setup for 'LoadFromCommandLine'.
  std::shared_ptr<clang::PCHContainerOperations> pchContainerOps(
    new clang::PCHContainerOperations());
  clang::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticsEngine> diagnosticsEngine(
    clang::CompilerInstance::createDiagnostics(
      new clang::DiagnosticOptions));

  // Run the Clang parser to produce an AST.
  std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTUnit> ast(clang::ASTUnit::LoadFromCommandLine(
    argv,
    argv + argc,
    pchContainerOps,
    diagnosticsEngine,
    llvm::StringRef() /*ResourceFilesPath, evidently ignored*/));

  if (ast == nullptr ||
      diagnosticsEngine->getNumErrors() > 0) {
    // Error messages have already been printed.
    return 2;
  }

  Visitor visitor(ast.get());
  visitor.traverseTU();

  return 0;
}


// EOF
```

`Makefile`:

```
# Makefile

# Default target.
all:
.PHONY: all


# ---- Configuration ----
# Installation directory from a binary distribution.
# Has five subdirectories: bin include lib libexec share.
# Downloaded from: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-14.0.0/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz
CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR = $(HOME)/opt/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04

# ---- llvm-config query results ----
# Program to query the various LLVM configuration options.
LLVM_CONFIG := $(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/llvm-config

# C++ compiler options to ensure ABI compatibility.
LLVM_CXXFLAGS := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --cxxflags)

# Directory containing the clang library files, both static and dynamic.
LLVM_LIBDIR := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --libdir)

# Other flags needed for linking, whether statically or dynamically.
LLVM_LDFLAGS_AND_SYSTEM_LIBS := $(shell $(LLVM_CONFIG) --ldflags --system-libs)


# ---- Compiler options ----
# C++ compiler.
#CXX = g++
CXX := $(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)/bin/clang++

# Compiler options, including preprocessor options.
CXXFLAGS =
CXXFLAGS += -Wall
CXXFLAGS += -Werror

# Silence a warning about a multi-line comment in DeclOpenMP.h.
CXXFLAGS += -Wno-comment

# Get llvm compilation flags.
CXXFLAGS += $(LLVM_CXXFLAGS)

# Tell the source code where the clang installation directory is.
CXXFLAGS += -DCLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR='"$(CLANG_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR)"'

# Linker options.
LDFLAGS =

# Pull in clang+llvm via libclang-cpp.so, which has everything, but is
# only available as a dynamic library.
LDFLAGS += -lclang-cpp

# Arrange for the compiled binary to search the libdir for that library.
# Otherwise, one can set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH envvar before running it.
# Note: the -rpath switch does not work on Windows.
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath=$(LLVM_LIBDIR)

# Get the needed -L search path, plus things like -ldl.
LDFLAGS += $(LLVM_LDFLAGS_AND_SYSTEM_LIBS)


# ---- Recipes ----
# Compile a C++ source file.
%.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<

# Executable.
all: deleted-ctor.exe
deleted-ctor.exe: deleted-ctor.o
    $(CXX) -g -Wall -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Test.
.PHONY: run
run: deleted-ctor.exe
    ./deleted-ctor.exe test.cc

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.exe


# EOF
```

`test.cc`:

```
// test.cc
// Test for deleted-ctor.exe.

// Explicit ctor, not deleted.
class END {
public:
  END();
};

// Explicit ctor, deleted.
class ED {
public:
  ED()=delete;
};


// Implicit ctor, not deleted.
class IND {
public:
};

// Implicit ctor, deleted.
class ID {
public:
  int &i;
};

// EOF
```

Example run:

```
$ make run
./deleted-ctor.exe test.cc
CXXRecord "END" at test.cc:5:7:
  CXXConstructor "END::END" type="void (void)" at test.cc:7:3: deleted=0
  CXXConstructor "END::END" type="void (const class END &)" at test.cc:5:7: deleted=0
  CXXConstructor "END::END" type="void (class END &&)" at test.cc:5:7: deleted=0
CXXRecord "ED" at test.cc:11:7:
  CXXConstructor "ED::ED" type="void (void)" at test.cc:13:3: deleted=1
  CXXConstructor "ED::ED" type="void (const class ED &)" at test.cc:11:7: deleted=0
  CXXConstructor "ED::ED" type="void (class ED &&)" at test.cc:11:7: deleted=0
CXXRecord "IND" at test.cc:18:7:
  CXXConstructor "IND::IND" type="void (void)" at test.cc:18:7: deleted=0
  CXXConstructor "IND::IND" type="void (const class IND &)" at test.cc:18:7: deleted=0
  CXXConstructor "IND::IND" type="void (class IND &&)" at test.cc:18:7: deleted=0
CXXRecord "ID" at test.cc:23:7:
  CXXConstructor "ID::ID" type="void (void)" at test.cc:23:7: deleted=1
  CXXConstructor "ID::ID" type="void (const class ID &)" at test.cc:23:7: deleted=0
  CXXConstructor "ID::ID" type="void (class ID &&)" at test.cc:23:7: deleted=0
```

Observe that the first constructor for each of `ED` and `ID` is labeled
with `deleted=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit constructors don't exist in the AST under `CXXRecordDecl` nodes but only under `DefinitionData`.

You can use `Sema::ForceDeclarationOfImplicitMembers` in AST plugin to get the constructors, then check whether is deleted.

```
// force declaration of implict constructors
clang::Sema &sema = Instance.getSema();
sema.ForceDeclarationOfImplicitMembers(const_cast<CXXRecordDecl*>(cxxRecordDecl));

// then check whether constructor is deleted
for (const auto* ctor : cxxRecordDecl->ctors()) {
    if (ctor->isDeleted() {
       // do something
    }
}
```