# How VisitNamedDecl and VisitCXXRecordDecl are called by RecursiveASTVisitor?

Tags: clang, libtooling

In `RecursiveASTVisitor`s [doc](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html), there is are no virtual methods of name VisitNamedDecl, VisitCXXRecordDecl ..etc.
So how they are called automatically called ?

Comment: I think some methods are called by CRTP, and those CRTP's are generated by macros.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that make the design of
[`RecursiveASTVisitor`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html)
difficult to understand:

1. It uses the
   [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)
   (CRTP) to dispatch to the user-provided methods, rather than the more
   conventional (but possibly slower) technique of using C++ `virtual`
   methods.
2. The vast majority of the overrideable methods are declared using a
   somewhat complex system of macros and multiply-included header files,
   the latter being generated by a special tool during the build.
   Among the consequences is that
   [doxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen), which generates
   the published documentation you (and I) linked to, cannot see them.

The dispatch design is explained somewhat in the
[Detailed Description](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html#details)
section of the documentation, but I'll provide my own explanation to
fill in some missing details.

Due to the second issue, I will be using fragments of preprocessor
output.  For concreteness, I am preprocessing
`deleted-ctor.cc`, the code I recently posted to
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76747902/2659307), but the
any preprocessesed form of `RecursiveASTVisitor.h` should match the
parts I am showing.

### The visitor dispatch mechanism

Let's focus on `VisitNamedDecl` since it was mentioned in the
question.  The template class definition, after preprocessing (and some
indentation using the [`indent`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/indent)
tool and other minor edits for readability), looks like:

```
template <typename Derived>
class RecursiveASTVisitor {
public:
  ...
  Derived &getDerived() { return *static_cast<Derived *>(this); }
  ...
  bool TraverseDecl(Decl *D);
  bool TraverseLabelDecl(LabelDecl *D);
  ...
  bool WalkUpFromDecl(Decl *D)
  {
    return getDerived().VisitDecl(D);
  }

  bool WalkUpFromNamedDecl(NamedDecl *D)
  {
    if (!getDerived().WalkUpFromDecl(D))
      return false;
    if (!getDerived().VisitNamedDecl(D))
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  bool VisitNamedDecl(NamedDecl *D)
  {
    return true;
  }

  bool WalkUpFromLabelDecl(LabelDecl *D)
  {
    if (!getDerived().WalkUpFromNamedDecl(D))
      return false;
    if (!getDerived().VisitLabelDecl(D))
      return false;
    return true;
  }
  ...
};
```

The `Traverse` methods are the entry points.  They call the
`WalkUpFrom` methods, which "walk up" the C++ class hierarchy and
invoke the `Visit` methods for classes of which the AST node in
question is an instance.

The `getDerived` method is a key element of the CRTP mechanism.  By
invoking methods on it, instead of `this` directly, any method defined
in `Derived` will (statically) override the corresponding base class
method.

The superclass `TraverseDecl` method does a dynamic dispatch based on
the type of its argument:

```
template <typename Derived>
bool RecursiveASTVisitor<Derived>::TraverseDecl(Decl *D)
{
  ...
  switch (D->getKind()) {
    ...
    case Decl::Label:
      if (!getDerived().TraverseLabelDecl(static_cast<LabelDecl *>(D)))
        return false;
      break;
    ...
  }
  return true;
}
```

I've chosen to focus on
[`LabelDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1LabelDecl.html)
because it is a concrete class derived from the abstract `NamedDecl`.
Its `Traverse` method looks like this:

```
template <typename Derived>
bool RecursiveASTVisitor<Derived>::TraverseLabelDecl(LabelDecl *D)
{
  bool ShouldVisitChildren = true;
  bool ReturnValue = true;

  if (!getDerived().shouldTraversePostOrder())
    if (!getDerived().WalkUpFromLabelDecl(D))
      return false;

  if (ReturnValue && ShouldVisitChildren)
    if (!getDerived().TraverseDeclContextHelper(dyn_cast<DeclContext>(D)))
      return false;

  if (ReturnValue) {
    for (auto *I : D->attrs())
      if (!getDerived().getDerived().TraverseAttr(I))
        return false;
  }

  if (ReturnValue && getDerived().shouldTraversePostOrder())
    if (!getDerived().WalkUpFromLabelDecl(D))
      return false;

  return ReturnValue;
}
```

The idea is it calls `WalkUpFrom` on the current node, and `Traverse`
on the child nodes.  There are two calls to `WalkUpFrom` because the
visitor can operate in either pre-order or post-order mode.  Again,
all calls go through `getDerived`, so can be overridden.

### The macro metaprogramming system

Going back to the definition of `RecursiveASTVisitor`, the first
part of the class is defined directly in
[`RecursiveASTVisitor.h`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/RecursiveASTVisitor_8h_source.html).

But then we get to this part of the header file, which declares the
`Traverse` methods for the `Decl` hierarchy:

```
// ---- Methods on Decls ----

// Declare Traverse*() for all concrete Decl classes.
#define ABSTRACT_DECL(DECL)
#define DECL(CLASS, BASE) bool Traverse##CLASS##Decl(CLASS##Decl *D);
#include "clang/AST/DeclNodes.inc"
  // The above header #undefs ABSTRACT_DECL and DECL upon exit.
```

`DeclNodes.inc` is a file generated during the build from
[`DeclNodes.td`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/include/clang/Basic/DeclNodes.td)
using a tool called [TableGen](https://llvm.org/docs/TableGen/).
In `DeclNodes.inc`, we find (among many other things):

```
#ifndef NAMED
#  define NAMED(Type, Base) DECL(Type, Base)
#endif
ABSTRACT_DECL(NAMED(Named, Decl))
...
#ifndef LABEL
#  define LABEL(Type, Base) NAMED(Type, Base)
#endif
LABEL(Label, NamedDecl)
```

Given the definitions of `ABSTRACT_DECL` and `DECL` that appear just
before the `#include`, we see that `ABSTRACT_DECL(NAMED(Named, Decl))`
expands to nothing, and:

```
LABEL(Label, NamedDecl)         expands to
NAMED(Label, NamedDecl)         which expands to
DECL(Label, NamedDecl)          which expands to
bool TraverseLabelDecl(LabelDecl *D);
```

Next in `RecursiveASTVisitor.h` we have:

```
  // Define WalkUpFrom*() and empty Visit*() for all Decl classes.
  bool WalkUpFromDecl(Decl *D) { return getDerived().VisitDecl(D); }
  bool VisitDecl(Decl *D) { return true; }
#define DECL(CLASS, BASE)                                                      \
  bool WalkUpFrom##CLASS##Decl(CLASS##Decl *D) {                               \
    TRY_TO(WalkUpFrom##BASE(D));                                               \
    TRY_TO(Visit##CLASS##Decl(D));                                             \
    return true;                                                               \
  }                                                                            \
  bool Visit##CLASS##Decl(CLASS##Decl *D) { return true; }
#include "clang/AST/DeclNodes.inc"
```

After concretely defining `WalkUpFromDecl` and `VisitDecl`, this defines
`WalkUpFrom` and `Visit` for the subclasses.  I won't go through all the
macro expansion details for these.

Finally, `TraverseLabelDecl` comes from this macro:

```
// This macro makes available a variable D, the passed-in decl.
#define DEF_TRAVERSE_DECL(DECL, CODE)                                          \
  template <typename Derived>                                                  \
  bool RecursiveASTVisitor<Derived>::Traverse##DECL(DECL *D) {                 \
    bool ShouldVisitChildren = true;                                           \
    bool ReturnValue = true;                                                   \
    if (!getDerived().shouldTraversePostOrder())                               \
      TRY_TO(WalkUpFrom##DECL(D));                                             \
    { CODE; }                                                                  \
    if (ReturnValue && ShouldVisitChildren)                                    \
      TRY_TO(TraverseDeclContextHelper(dyn_cast<DeclContext>(D)));             \
    if (ReturnValue) {                                                         \
      /* Visit any attributes attached to this declaration. */                 \
      for (auto *I : D->attrs())                                               \
        TRY_TO(getDerived().TraverseAttr(I));                                  \
    }                                                                          \
    if (ReturnValue && getDerived().shouldTraversePostOrder())                 \
      TRY_TO(WalkUpFrom##DECL(D));                                             \
    return ReturnValue;                                                        \
  }
```

and this use of it:

```
DEF_TRAVERSE_DECL(LabelDecl, {// There is no code in a LabelDecl.
                             })
```

Other `Traverse` methods have (hand-written) code inside the braces that
calls `Traverse` on child nodes.

The result of all this mechanism is the compiler sees `Traverse`,
`WalkUpFrom`, and `Visit` methods for all AST classes, much of it
generated automatically, but doxygen can't see most of it.